# How would I keep a fixed nav on top at all times in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

Well I am working on creating my own personal website, it is a one page scrollable website with a fixed navigation at the top. I added a JQuery light box gallery from code I found online, it works fine, the only problem is when I am scrolling past the gallery, the tiles scroll up over my fixed navigation. Is there a way I can make it so my nav is always on top? Or do I have to edit the actual gallery plugin itself.

Comment: You're probably looking for the `z-index` property.

Comment: Can you add the actual HTML/CSS that you have?, maybe a screenshot illustrating the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `z-index` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) controls how elements overlap with each other. If you set your navbar's `z-index` to a higher value than that of the gallery, it will appear on top.

Comment: Yes, *if* the element hierarchy supports it. `z-index` doesn't apply to cousin elements. In that case order wins out.

Comment: Yeah, that's a pretty important caveat!

Answer (score 0):

In your situations their might be either of the two reasons to cause that:

1) Naturally, galleries should always be on top (it is the point of interest). So its CSS `z-index` might be set to a high value that tops on your`nav`

**Solution** : check the parent class of the gallery and see its `z-index` then give a higher `z-index` to your `nav`

2) Second case is rare to happen but it might still happen, so far it is clear that your `nav` has `position:fixed`. But the Gallery might not have set the position implicitly, so it is by default static which might cause this mysterious behaviour of layering

**Solution** : check the parent element of the gallery and add give a position property implicitly (AFTER CHECKING IF IT DOES NOT REALLY HAVE IT)